# Active Admin: View Has No Content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I occasionally have views in ActiveAdmin that are blank (apart from perhaps the title). This happened recently with the "Show" view for a frequently used table, for example (but it has happened with "Edit" and other views in the past as well).

In the past I have just renamed the tables and have found that this tends to work. But I'm thinking there's got to be a better way.

Specifically, I have the following two questions:

1. What is the best approach for debugging this general kind of issue in ActiveAdmin, given that most of view logic is hidden somewhere "under the hood"?
2. Is this particular issue (not displaying anything except the title for a view that should have more content) a known one? Are there known workarounds?